# Is the "staff credits" music in DKC Tropical Freeze accessible aside from beating the game?

Tags: donkey-kong-country-tropical-freeze

It doesn't seem to be listed the the music section of the extras. The only place I can find it is on YouTube, and both there and in the credits the song fades out prematurely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Update as of 2021:

[Thanks to VGMdb](https://vgmdb.net/product/9026) we now have all the composers and people involved in the soundtrack for Donkey Kong Country Tropical Freeze:

**Audio Supervisor:** Scott Petersen

**Music:** David Wise

****Contract Audio:**** Chris Carroll, Kenneth Bassham, Bobby Arlauskas, Clark Crawford, Matt Piersall, Matthew Thies, GL33k LLC

****Music Supervisor:**** Kenji Yamamoto

**Music/Voice Recording:** Daisuke Matsuoka, Minako Hamano, Shinji Ushiroda, Riyu Tamura

*Original post:*

As far as I can tell, the soundtrack for Donkey Kong Country Tropical Freeze is not for sale (yet). As such, one needs to turn to unofficial fan made rips instead.

I found this on Youtube. It's 4mins 13sec. Is that still too short?

[DKC Tropical Freeze End Credits](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mFIQI1yT838)

Edit: Someone on Youtube commented that: "The only bad thing about the song is that it fades out". So it would suggest that's how the song is.